# 500 - Internal server error - after integration of Wordpress in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress

i am working on asp.net mvc application. Recently i have integrated wordpress in my website in seprate directory

> www.mysite.com/blog

blog is working fine but i am getting **500 - Internal server error.** when i am trying to login.

> www.mysite.com/blog/wp-login.php

If i removed web.config file and try to login then its working.I think there is missing some thing in my web.config file or any other issue.

Any suggestion to figure out this issue ?

I am going to update my question.

when i put on show iis error option.now this error is showing

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

C:\Php5\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout
```

I have no idea why this error is generating?

Comment: Look in the error log for the exact error message

Comment: look at the server's event logs for details about the 500.

Comment: getting following error HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Php5\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout

Answer (score 0):

I have to changed my web.config setting.Now it is working fine

**Previous setting is this**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

**After Changing setting**

```
        <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
        </system.webServer>
```